# java "ClassNotFoundException" error

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception, scribe

I am new to java programming and I am getting the much-maligned error "ClassNotFoundException" error.

The strange thing is is that it compiles fine:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
steve@steve-ThinkPad-T61:~/facebook$ java  FacebookProg  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/scribe/builder/ServiceBuilder  
    at FacebookProg.main(FacebookProg.java:8)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)  
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)  
    ... 1 more
```

I checked online and it seems that java can't find the library at runtime that it was able to find at compile time. So tried the following variations:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg  
java -cp /usr/share/java/ FacebookProg  
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java"; java FacebookProf  
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar"; java FacebookProg
```

I checked several places on StackOverflow and google and still can't figure out why. I'm new to java, so there's probably a simple solution, but I can't find it. I am using Sun Java 1.6 64-bit on Ubuntu 11.04. The scribe-1.3.0.jar file is in "/usr/share/java" which, I believe, is the canonical place to put java packages.

The barebones code is here (in case it matters):

```
import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

public class FacebookProg {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(FacebookApi.class)
        .apiKey("blah_blah")
        .apiSecret("blah_blah")
        .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a total Java noob, and was getting mixed up between options for the `javac` and `java` commands. My issue was that I was using the `-cp` flag on the compile, but not on the execute. My code worked fine when I used the option on both: `javac -cp .:/my/full/path/myjar.jar test.java; java -cp .:/my/full/path/myjar.jar test`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classpath has to point to BOTH the directory of the external library you are using AND the class you are trying to run itself. Try this:

Windows:

```
java -cp .;/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

Linux:

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

By the way , to compile it you should have run this:

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Although there should be a beginning slash mark in front of "usr/". Here: java -cp .:/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg

Comment: You're welcome. I can tell you from a programmer's eye that learning through experience is far more valuable than knowledge gained from books and tutorials. I'm glad it came to use today.

As for the slash before usr , well i'm not so familiar with the linux directory structure , so i'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

means you are running the `FacebookProg` class, not compiling it.

If you leave the `-cp ...` out, you are leaving the vital classpath out, so the JVM cannot find the classes `FacebookProg` requires.

To compile, you need

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg.java
```

(note the `javac`, instead of `java` to invoke the compiler)

To run, you already know how to.

Also, you have errors in the follwoing lines:

```
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java"; java FacebookProf     
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar"; java FacebookProg
```

The first misspells `FacebookProg` and does not have the required jar on the classpath, the second has the wrong path to the jar.  Try

```
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar"; java FacebookProg
```

Also, make sure the jar is indeed located at `/usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar`

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar FacebookProg
```

This should work fine if you compiled the FacebookProg.class in same directory. You can try `java -cp /usr/share/java/scribe-1.3.0.jar:/locationOfFacebookProg.class directory/ FacebookProg`

Answer (score 0):

suppose that, the directory of your program is

$HOME

$HOME/lib/*.jar

you can write a script like:

```
for file in "$HOME/lib/*.jar"
    do
        if [ -f $file ]
        then 
            CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
        else
            echo ignore $file
        fi
done

java  -cp $CLASSPATH FacebookProg
```